# How to customize the upload button on Uploadthing?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, next.js

I followed the instructions on the page https://docs.uploadthing.com/nextjs/pagedir to upload images to uploadthing.com, and everything is working fine. Now I want to customize the upload button, so how can I do that?
Below is the code in my application:

```
import { UploadButton } from "~/utils/uploadthing";
 
export default function Home() {
  return (
    <main className="flex min-h-screen flex-col items-center justify-between p-24">
      <UploadButton
        endpoint="imageUploader"
        onClientUploadComplete={(res) => {
          // Do something with the response
          console.log("Files: ", res);
          alert("Upload Completed");
        }}
        onUploadError={(error: Error) => {
          // Do something with the error.
          alert(`ERROR! ${error.message}`);
        }}
      />
    </main>
  );
}
```

Example: Can I replace the upload button with an image or SVG? If yes, how can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

To do so, you need to update your `UploadButton` component. You can add `svg` or `progressbars` or anything you like.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback!
I followed the [uploadthing docs](https://docs.uploadthing.com/nextjs/pagedir) instructions, but I don't see the `<UploadButton .../>` component.

Comment: Your upload button should be in `~/utils/uploadthing`, share that code

Comment: Here is `~/utils/uploadthing`

```
import { generateComponents } from "@uploadthing/react";
 
import type { OurFileRouter } from "~/server/uploadthing";
 
export const { UploadButton, UploadDropzone, Uploader } =
  generateComponents<OurFileRouter>();
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use [React Uploady](https://github.com/rpldy/react-uploady). The tutorial you are using is very much dependent on the library and lot of details are encapsulated.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! [UploadThing](https://uploadthing.com/) is still more suitable for my application. I have seen repositories on GitHub using [App Router (app/)](https://docs.uploadthing.com/nextjs/appdir), but my application uses version next 12 [Page Router (pages/)](https://docs.uploadthing.com/nextjs/pagedir). I hope someone can help me out .

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by using the property of appearance, this will allow you to style your "button", "container" and other uploadthing button. By simple doing that you can copy this code

```
import { UploadButton } from "~/utils/uploadthing";
 
export default function Home() {
  return (
    <main className="flex min-h-screen flex-col items-center justify-between p-24">
      <UploadButton
        endpoint="imageUploader"
        appearance={{
            button: {
              background: "yellow",
              padding: "2rem",
              color: "#000",
            },
            container: {
              display: "flex",
              background: "gray",
            },
        onClientUploadComplete={(res) => {
          // Do something with the response
          console.log("Files: ", res);
          alert("Upload Completed");
        }}
        onUploadError={(error: Error) => {
          // Do something with the error.
          alert(`ERROR! ${error.message}`);
        }}
      />
    </main>
  );
}
```

By doing that you can style your uploadthing button using native CSS codes.